# Codesys how to write to output in Wago 750

Tags: plc, ssi, codesys

I have Wago 750-880 with different sensors. Someone wrote already a program to control it in Codesys. I would like to return (I have a Java background :D) - to write some variables to output in the driver, e.g. holding registers. I would like to to read later those variables (parameters) on a SSI page like that

```html
<!--#READPI ADR=QX4.5&FORMAT=%X-->
```

I don't have any PLC experience :(
How can I write to the Holding Register?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Not having experience means you should do research and try to figure it out! When you've tried something and run into a wall give us another shout :)

Comment: What is SSI? How do you connect to PLC? Ethernet? What is communication protocol? modbus? ProfiBus? Can?

Comment: @SergeyRomanov: SSI in a web-serving context is probably Server-Side Include, which e.g. Apache uses for basic dynamic page generation using very much the format in the codeblock.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question is that you'd like the information to be reflected on a web interface or screen?

If so, in Wago's environment there is a VISU facility that you can enable to display whatever you'd like, and access it via a web browser over the internet.

This may help: [Supplement to the User Manual for  PLC Programming with CoDeSys 2.3](http://www.dimoulas.com.gr/PDF/WAGO%20PLC/CoDeSys_Visu_E.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

create variables for your I/O and using the Modbus library to access your %MW??? variables.
First %MW0 is at address 12288 and so on

ex: Input1 AT %MW10 ; //12288 + 10 = 12298

//MAP TO ACTUAL IP1 unit channel 1
Input1.0 = IP1.0